# How to create filtered index with NOT IN in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I want to create UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX which restrict some records for particular column I am using NOT IN to filter it but I am getting error becuase of NOT IN. what is the alternative to do it?

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
[UN_Student] ON [dbo].[Student]
(
[School_Cd] ASC,
[Class_Id] ASC,
[Enroll_Dt] ASC,
[Email_Id] ASC
)
WHERE ([School_Cd]='EM' AND [Class_Id] NOT IN (1,2,3))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtered indexes cannot use `NOT IN`.  You can use multiple `AND` operators instead.  Brent Ozar has very a good article [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/) regarding what is and isn't allowed for filtered indexes.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
[UN_Student] ON [dbo].[Student]
(
[School_Cd] ASC,
[Class_Id] ASC,
[Enroll_Dt] ASC,
[Email_Id] ASC
)
WHERE ([School_Cd]='EM' AND [Class_Id] <> 1 AND [Class_Id] <> 2 AND [Class_Id] <> 3)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
..WHERE ([School_Cd]='EM' AND ([Class_Id] <> 1 AND [Class_Id] <> 2 AND [Class_Id] <> 3))
```

Comment: It is recommended to provide more context to your answer. Review the guide on how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answerv

Comment: my answer seemed self-explanatory to me

Comment: but I guess it could have been placed here as a comment